# How do I get the path to the perl script that I only know the PID of?

Tags: linux, perl

I had a problem recently, where a perl script was consuming server resources. I found out it was a perl script by using "top". But it didn't give the path to the script. Nor did `ps`.
Also, ps -ef showed that the process with that pid is `/usr/bin/httpd` (apache), so it must have been apache serving some perl page I suppose.

Is it possible to get the path to currently running perl script, if I only know the process PID of the perl process that is running that script? If so, how?

Clarification: I don't need the path to the perl binary, *I need the path to the perl script that binary is currently executing.*

Comment: `ps aux` should tell you when the perl process was started, combine with Apache access logs to find the responsible script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `ps -p $p -o command` , where instead of $p you use the PID of the process. This gives the full command line.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in /proc for the PID of the process.  In there is a file `cmdline`

That contains the command that was used to run the script.

eg:

```
$ cat /proc/19433/cmdline
perl/path/to/myscript
```

There is actually \000 (chr(0) / NULL) between the "perl" and the "/path..." but cat doesn't show it.

Comment: I also just found out by accident, that pressing c while viewing "top" output gives the full command names. Neat :)